Remove an element from the array (Python): time and space complexity
For the task:

Given an integer array nums and an integer val, remove all occurrences of val in nums in-place. The order of the elements may be changed. Then return the number of elements in nums which are not equal to val.
Consider the number of elements in nums which are not equal to val be k, to get accepted, you need to do the following things:
Change the array nums such that the first k elements of nums contain the elements which are not equal to val. The remaining elements of nums are not important as well as the size of nums.
Return k.

I wrote a following solution:
    for value in nums[:]:
            if value == val:
                nums.remove(value)
        return len(nums)

However, the solution seems to be ineffective due to the time and space complexity. The question is if I am estimating it correctly.

So, for the creation of the array cope nums[:] the complexity is O(n)
We iterate through each element of the array once: O(n)

The resulting time complexity will be O(n^2) with space complexity O(n), or?
Thanks in advance for the comments and input!

I think your time complexity should be O(m*n) where m is the number of occurences of val in nums. remove(value) will iterate your nums array and remove the first occurence of value. you could do something like "while in remove" or use something like "new_nums = [n for n in nums if n != val]".

@Steffen list comprehension is not in-place.

Did your task specify that you have to use a list to implement the array? A dict with integer keys would allow for faster removal. (Well, not quite integer keys, but tuples, for example, that could be used to distinguish between duplicate values.)

The complexity is O(n^2), but not because of what you listed. Copying a list is O(n), but we do it ever only once, so it will not make complexity worse than O(n).
The reason for O(n^2) is that .remove on a list is O(n) complexity operation on its own. Since we possibly have no remove all n elements, this makes our worse-case scenario complexity O(n^2).
But, there are 2 hints in the task that can lead us to O(n) solution:
"The order of the elements may be changed" and "Change the array nums such that the first k elements of nums contain the elements which are not equal to val"
The key is to take elements equal to val that are in k first elements, and swap them with elements not equal to val that are in remaining elements.
nums = [1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,1]

first = 0
last = len(nums)-1

val = 1

while True:
    while nums[first] != val: # Find first val in a list
        first += 1
    while nums[last] == val: # Find last non-val in a list
        last -= 1
    if first > last: # Our pointers crossed, we are done
        break
    nums[first], nums[last] = nums[last], nums[first] # Swap elements
print(nums) # [5, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
print(first) # 4

nums will now contain all non-val items on the first k spots, and first will contain value of k.

Based on the question, i think this should be the desired algorithm:
nums = [1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,1]
val = 1

k = 0
for x in range(0,len(nums)):
    if nums[x] != val:
       nums[k] = nums[x]
       k = k + 1
print(nums) # [2,3,4,5,1,4,1,5,1,1]
print(k) # 4

(Only the first k elements are correct, the remaining elements are irelevant)
Complexity: O(n)

Doesn't seem to work.

you are right, fixed it.

The analysis you made, has two mistakes:

It multiplies complexities that should not be multiplied: the nums[:] task is completed first, before the iteration over that sequeunce starts, so that would only account for O(+), not O(²)

It assumes that remove has a time complexity of O(1), which is not true.


remove is not efficient for this task: it will have to move all values that follow the given index, which has an average time complexity of O(). As you may have to call remove many times, possibly O() times, your implementation has a worst case time complexity of O(²). The operation of nums[:] has no impact on the overall time complexity, as O(+²) is still O(²).
As to the space complexity, you are right, it is O(). If we only look at the auxiliary space complexity, so excluding the memory already allocated for the input list, then we can do this with O(1) auxiliary space complexity.
For achieving both the desired time and space complexities, you could iterate the values that you need to keep (creating an iterator) and write these into your list from index 0 onwards:
    nums[:] = (num for num in nums if num != val)
    return len(nums)

